# jQuery Return elements where ID begins with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a lot of `<span>` tags like this `<span id='val_Title'></span> <span id='val_Name'></span>`

I would like to return all the elements that begin with 'val_' and hide them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) selectors

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span[id^='val_']").hide();
});
```

Comment: Not to be a web blanket - and I have already +1 this very elegant answer - but it does not "fully" answer the question.  The question asks to return a list and then hide.  So how would you "return a list" of the elements that begin with "X"?