# :contain / start by

Tags: jquery, filter

Is there a "start by" filter in jQuery, something like :contain but with a string beginning condition ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you can easily implement your own selector for jQuery:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    startsWith: function(elem,match) {  
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").indexOf(match[3]) == 0;
    }  
});
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$("p:startsWith(Hello)").css("color","red")
```

Comment: Thanks, and with cas insensitive :

// case insenstitive for live :contain
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
   "startWith": function(elem, i, match, array) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase
  ().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) == 0;
   }
});

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can do it yourself using `filter`, as pulse suggested:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('start') == 0 }
)
```

You may want to use a regular expression here, to ignore case, or for more advanced searches:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().match(/^start/i) }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) function in javascript

```
var str = "test string print";

str.indexOf ( "test" ) returns 0
```

and

```
str.indexOf ( "print" ) returns 12
```

So you can check for the return value of indexOf function and if it is 0 then it is at the start position.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start With: ^=
```

The ^= operator will filter elements whose attribute starts with the given value.

More info here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1003-Cool-jQuery-Predicate-Selectors.htm

[jQuery Return elements where ID begins with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897025/jquery-return-elements-where-id-begins-with-a-certain-string)

Comment: These selectors are useful, but they're for attributes, not for content.