# Set attribute disabled to options NOT containing a certain string

Tags: jquery, attributes

I know this should be easier if I could only use optgroups. But I am trying to avoid hacking core of my CMS, so jQuery should come to rescue again, hopefully.

I have a select with options in a hierarchy sometimes, and I want to put attributes disabled to any of options containing text NOT starting with a dash. 
I want to code like:

**Set disabled attributes to selectors with options text NOT starting with a dash ("-").**

```
<select id="options">
<option value="" selected="selected">- Please choose -</option>
<option value="1">Parent1</option>
<option value="2">-child1</option>
<option value="3">-child2</option>
<option value="4">-child3</option>
<option value="5">-child4</option>
<option value="6">Parent2</option>
<option value="7">-child5</option>
<option value="8">-child6</option>
<option value="9">-child7</option>
<option value="10">-child8</option>
</select>
```

The closest solution is here **[:contain / start by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012299/contain-start-by)**,

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    startsWith: function(elem,match) {  
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").indexOf(match[3]) == 0;
    }  
});
```

But I can't seem to do it right this far.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
​$("#options option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("-") !== 0;
}​).attr('disabled', true);​​
```

This filters out any elements that don't have text starting with `"-"`, [you can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld4nk/).

The custom selector approach, like your question, would be this:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    startsWith: function(a, b, match) {
        return $(a).text().indexOf(match[3]) === 0;
    }  
});

$("#options option:not(:startsWith(-))").attr('disabled', true);​
```

[You can see a demo of that method here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab3qE/).

Comment: You are my hero, Nick. Works like a charm. This should also help lots of CMS users with this limitation who may be lucky to find this. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: BTW, for learning purposes, Can I put .attr('disabled', 'disabled');​​ there as well instead? Thanks

Comment: With the second option, I was almost there save for the part of ":not(:" about which I was confused with ".not". Thanks

Comment: @kuswantin - It's better to use `.attr('disabled', bool)` and `.attr('readonly', bool)` in this case, since jQuery actually operates on the DOM. `disabled="disabled"` just sets true because `"disabled" !== false`, it weak type converts to true.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Wish I had clear understanding of this great software from head to toes :) But I am glad that I am always lucky to find help like you. Thanks