# Filtering elements from the start of button string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can enable the code to start filtering from the beginning of the text of buttons?

As you can see what is happening now is filtering all letters doesn't matter where it located. For example, while passing a as filter I am getting `North America` as well, which is not what I want.

```js
function checkFilter(filter) {
  const jqCollection = $('.list .list-item:contains(' + filter + ')');
  if (jqCollection.length) {
    jqCollection.css("background",'red');
  }
}

checkFilter('a');
```

```css
body{ padding:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Africa</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Antarctica</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Asia</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Europe</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">North America</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Australia</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">South America</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the top answers for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012299/contain-start-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `.contains()` and instead use `.indexOf` and see if the result is 0.  JQuery is not needed for such a simple operation.

```js
function checkFilter(filter) {
  const buttons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("button.list-item"));
  buttons.forEach(function(btn){
    if(btn.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) === 0){
      btn.classList.add("match");
    } 
  });
}

checkFilter('a');
```

```css
body{ padding:30px;}
.match { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Africa</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Antarctica</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Asia</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Europe</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">North America</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">Australia</button>
 <button class="list-item" type="button">South America</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's hardly anything jQuery is needed for any more except sometimes jQuery datatables.

Comment: Thanks Scott can you also let me know why Filter case is sensitive? For example the `checkFilter('A');` is not returning anything

Comment: @MonaCoder Strings are case-sensitive. In my answer, I'm taking the text you want to search and forcing it to a new String that is all lower case (the `.toLowerCase()` method call) and then comparing it against a lower case filter string of `"a"`. This ensures that no matter how the text is written, if you always pass `filter` as a lower-case string, you will never have a case mismatch situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's vanilla JS along with ES6' `String.prototype.startsWith`:

```js
function checkFilter(filter) {
  const jqCollection = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list .list-item')] // get all list-items
    .filter(el => // now filter them
      el.textContent
      .toLowerCase() // keeping an element only if it's lower-cased textcontent
      .startsWith(filter.toLowerCase()) // starts with the lower-cased letter passed as "filter"
    );
  jqCollection.forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'); // now iterate over the filtered result
}

checkFilter('a');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <button class="list-item" type="button">Africa</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">Antarctica</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">Asia</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">Europe</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">North America</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">Australia</button>
  <button class="list-item" type="button">South America</button>
</div>
```