# Count elements that the id begins with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Return elements where ID begins with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897025/jquery-return-elements-where-id-begins-with-a-certain-string)

Ok, let's say I have the following elements:

```
<select id="state_id" value="20">test1</select>
<select id="state_id1" value="21">test2</select>
<select id="state_id2" value="22">test3</select>
```

How can I get the `length()` of the select tags that the id begins with `state_id` in this case?

I have tried: `$("^#state_id").length();` but no success.

Any hint?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('[id^=state_]').length
```